# toggleclass and first margin

Tags: jquery, html, css

in the first , i dont speak english very well 
second : my problem is about "toggleclass"

I'm new to jquery and javacript and this is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.humburger').click(function(){
       $('#sidbar').toggleClass('side-lg-tog');
       $('#contenu').toggleClass('contenu-lg-tog');
   });
});
</script>

<style> 
   body {
       margin:0; padding:0;
   }

   #entete {
       height:50px;
       background-color:#197aac;
       position:relative;
   }

   .humburger {
       position:absolute;
       top:17px;
       left:15px;
       cursor:pointer;
   }

   .humburger span {
       background-color:#fff;
       display:block;
       height:2px;
       width:20px;
       margin-bottom:3px;
   }

   #sidbar {
       width:300px;
       height:100%;
       background-color:#e7e7e7; 
       border-right:1px solid #ccc;
       position:absolute;
       top:50px;
       left:0;
       transition:transform .3s ease-in-out;  
   }

   .side-lg-tog{transform:translate(-240px, 0);}
   .contenu-lg-tog {margin-left:60px;!important}

   #contenu {
       background-color:#eff8fd;   
       height:100%;
       margin-left:300px;
       padding:15px 30px;
       transition:margin-left .3s ease-in-out;
   }

   .pad-contenu {
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       min-height:300px;
       background-color:#fff;
   }

   @media (max-width:767px){
    #sidbar{transform:translate(-300px, 0);color:red;}
    #contenu {margin-left:0;}
   }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="entete">
       <div class="humburger">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidbar">test</div>
    <div id="toggle-btn"></div>
    <div id="contenu">
        <div class="pad-contenu">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when i click in my humburger the side bar make the translation perfectly by using the new class side-lg-tog `$('#sidbar').toggleClass('side-lg-tog');` but content Keeps the first `margin-left:300px;`  and i want it to be `60px`, 
thanks and sorry for my english , my second language is frensh .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in the statement `.contenu-lg-tog {margin-left:60px;!important}`.

You need to put semicolon after "!important". Just write:

```
.contenu-lg-tog {
   margin-left:60px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it can done by

```
document.getElementsById("id")[0].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
```

[0] refer to element you want to change in order by write.

Also can done by

```
element.style.CSS_Property = "Value";
```

`element` is the variable
See : [W3SCHOOL JS DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: `getElementsById` can't be an array, because of `ID` nature and just there's no `getElementsById` in javascript

Comment: @Banzay I know it's not array I mean it's like the array when using it